# Using the Enter Key to move between Textboxes

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

A user of one of my apps said that he was "expecting" the Enter key to move between the Textboxes.  Is there a way to do that with the Windows Phone?

See you can set the TabIndex of each control but do I have to write a lot of code to capture the onKeyDown?

Just wondering if there is an easy way to add this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One decent options is, by implementing logic to move between Textboxes as [Custom Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj682995%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Like done by Mike Hole as written in [his blog](http://mikehole.com/2011/01/12/wp7-text-boxes-onenter-my-1st-behaviour/). With Mike's custom behavior, we can simply attach that behavior to the textbox and specify control name to move focus to upon enter key pressed :

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtUsername">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <mh:OnEnter NextControlName="txtPassword" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```